# To_char ,To_date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

how do you become conform with this code, only dates of 2019 appear to me? You are not changing To_char.

```
SELECT GUEST.GNO, GUEST.GLASTNAME, GUEST.GFIRSTNAME, BOOKING.gNO, BOOKING.GINDATE 
FROM GUEST, BOOKING
WHERE GUEST.GNO = BOOKING.gNO AND BOOKING.GINDATE = TO_CHAR (GINDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. `TO_CHAR` converts a date to a string. `BOOKING.GINDATE = TO_CHAR (GINDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY')` compares a date with a string hence. Don't do that. If you are looking for 2019 only, one method would be `WHERE TO_CHAR(booking.gindate, 'YYYY') = '2019'`.

Comment: By the way: You are using a join syntax that was made redundant in the year 1992. So, please don't use comma-separated joins. Use modern ANSI joins, e.g. `FROM guest JOIN booking ON guest.gno = booking.gno`.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question, it is not easy to understand what you are really asking? Maybe add some sample data and expected output.

Comment: And SQL questions should always be tagged with the DBMS you are using (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, …). Which is it?

Comment: Sr mate but my English is low,but thanks mate u have me !!! i try him and i take access.. i cant use modern *all style's ...it is homework and wants some specifications

Comment: i use   ((Java SE 8u) (Oracle Express Edition 11g Release 2) ( SQL Developer)

Comment: If your class forces you to use this very old join syntax, then it's a bad class. Quit it, if you have the choice.

Comment: I'm at the beginning of the class,every month we learn new  syntax for all,that says the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am interpreting your query as you want bookings in 2019.  If so, then query should look more like this:

```
SELECT g.GNO, g.GLASTNAME, g.GFIRSTNAME, b.gNO, b.GINDATE 
FROM GUEST g JOIN
     BOOKING b
     ON g.GNO = b.gNO 
WHERE b.GINDATE >= DATE '2019-01-01' AND
      b.GINDATE < DATE '2020-01-01';
```

Of course, there might be slight variations depending on your database.